# prepending a menu designed with angular to other pages using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am having a menu item which is designed with angular js.

I want this menu to be used in other sites (cross domain is not an issue, it is taken care). I tried to load the page with jQuery and prepend it in the body using the below code

```
var $navDiv = $( "<div id='navbar'/>"); 
        $( "body" ).prepend($navDiv); 
        $( "#navbar" ).load("http://angularsiteurl");
```

This is loading the page, but the angular items are not working.

For example if the page is displaying

> Welcome {{user}}

instead of

> Welcome Vicky

is there any other way to load this angular menu using javascript/jQuery ?

Comment: i suppose you have to initiate an angular digest cycle

Answer (score 0):

Your issues are caused by the fact that Angular application that handles your menu template is not present/initialised on the site you are appending to.

You either need to include Angular library, or create a server-rendered service.